# DesktopCouch does not sync

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, desktopcouch

I have here two computers, both installed with Ubuntu 10.10. The Laptop uses the Netbook Edition. Both are connected, file sync and Tomboy Notes are working.

My Desktop syncs databases with Ubuntu One, my Laptop does not. If I delete for example the contacts Database on my Desktop, the database is back a view seconds later. If I delete the same database on my laptop, nothing happens. (I'm using Futon)

If I kill beam, delete the config and try to restart with the dbus-send I got an error

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/desktopcouch/+filebug?field.title=DesktopCouch+does+not+sync+%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fq%2F25463%2F711%5D), assign it to `thisfred` and comment back with the bug number (just in case). We'll answer the question here when we have enough information there.

Comment: Done. But I'm not shure if it is a bug or just a configuration issue

Comment: What's the bug #?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards